# How to use a Retrofit response in another places

Tags: android, retrofit

I am using Retrofit in my application and receiving data from my server.
I receive data from my server in responseBody in Retrofit, but when I want to use these received data, my array is null?!!

Here is my class:

```
public class ActivityApplicationsList extends Activity {
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_applications_list);

    Log.i(TAG , "size of response array: " +  populateDataFromServer().size())
    //this size is 0 but have to be 4 !
  }

  private ArrayList<StructApplication> populateDataFromServer() {

    final ArrayList<StructApplication> mine = new ArrayList<>();
    final APIService service = ServiceGenerator.createService(APIService.class, "2015-03-01 14:26:00", "123456", "123456");
    Call<ArrayList<AppModel>> call = service.getApp();

    call.enqueue(new Callback<ArrayList<AppModel>>() {
      @Override
      public void onResponse(Call<ArrayList<AppModel>> call, Response<ArrayList<AppModel>> response) {

          ArrayList<AppModel> newAppModel = response.body();

          for(int i=0 ; i < newAppModel.size();i++){

            StructApplication structApplication = new StructApplication();
            structApplication.setName(String.valueOf(newAppModel.get(i).getAppId()));
            structApplication.setId(newAppModel.get(i).getAppId());
            structApplication.setAppVersionReleaseDate(newAppModel.get(i).getAppVersionReDate());
            structApplication.setAppDeleted(newAppModel.get(i).getAppDeleted());

            mine.add(structApplication);
          }
      }

      @Override
      public void onFailure(Call<ArrayList<AppModel>> call, Throwable t) {
      }

    });

    return mine;
  }
}
```

And I debugged to make sure that all data received in onResponse:
[image: my correct response from server]

As you can see, I received all data correctly, but when I use this response in onCreate of this class it's null!

I really appreciate your answer about this weird problem.

Comment: make sure whenever your data come in response then after you do your action. if you want to see size of arraylist then after completion of for loop you can put log or any action you want to perform on response arraylist

Comment: boss your API is executing on the background thread and you are returning the arraylist after firing the API call which will going to take time in completion. instead of return execute a method inside onResponse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you are printing your list size before the response comes. As request is being sent asynchronously, and your are trying to get size before `onResponse()` callback method.
try to add this line

```
Log.i(TAG , "size of response array: " +  populateDataFromServer().size())
```

in `onResponse()` method after `mine.add(structApplication);` you will see the right size.

Answer (score 1):

Its return first and execute later, try this way...

```
 private ArrayList<StructApplication> populateDataFromServer() {

        final ArrayList<StructApplication> mine = new ArrayList<>();
        final APIService service = ServiceGenerator.createService(APIService.class, "2015-03-01 14:26:00", "123456", "123456");
        Call<ArrayList<AppModel>> call = service.getApp();

        Response<ArrayList<AppModel>> response = responseCall.execute();

        ArrayList<AppModel> newAppModel = response.body();

              for(int i=0 ; i < newAppModel.size();i++){

               StructApplication structApplication = new StructApplication();
               structApplication.setName(String.valueOf(newAppModel.get(i).getAppId()));
               structApplication.setId(newAppModel.get(i).getAppId());
               structApplication.setAppVersionReleaseDate(newAppModel.get(i).getAppVersionReDate());
               structApplication.setAppDeleted(newAppModel.get(i).getAppDeleted());

                mine.add(structApplication);
              }

       return mine;


      }
```

Comment: main method has return type is array. we need to pass mine array as return on success and failure method

Comment: This is still wrong without an AsyncTask. Nothing was wrong with `enqueue`

Comment: yes, this is sync method, it will load in main thread....if you need in async then you need to call inside async...this is the way for get the return response..

Comment: You can see the accepted answer or mine for the async way to get the answer

Answer (score 1):

It is happening due to api calling because api taking few seconds to get response and meanwhile you returned your `mine` array. So please return response once you got value from server.

Do like this

Make a global instance for this class like

```
public class ActivityApplicationsList extends Activity {
ArrayList<StructApplication> mine = new ArrayList();

@Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_applications_list);

     populateDataFromServer();

    Log.i(TAG , "size of response array: " +  mine.size());
  }




private void populateDataFromServer() {

    final APIService service = ServiceGenerator.createService(APIService.class, "2015-03-01 14:26:00", "123456", "123456");
    Call<ArrayList<AppModel>> call = service.getApp();

    call.enqueue(new Callback<ArrayList<AppModel>>() {
      @Override
      public void onResponse(Call<ArrayList<AppModel>> call, Response<ArrayList<AppModel>> response) {

          ArrayList<AppModel> newAppModel = response.body();

          for(int i=0 ; i < newAppModel.size();i++){

           StructApplication structApplication = new StructApplication();
           structApplication.setName(String.valueOf(newAppModel.get(i).getAppId()));
           structApplication.setId(newAppModel.get(i).getAppId());
           structApplication.setAppVersionReleaseDate(newAppModel.get(i).getAppVersionReDate());
           structApplication.setAppDeleted(newAppModel.get(i).getAppDeleted());

            mine.add(structApplication);
          }
      }

      @Override
      public void onFailure(Call<ArrayList<AppModel>> call, Throwable t) {
      }

    });    
  }
}
```

Comment: @cricket_007 Means??

Comment: Means this doesn't compile at all

Comment: It won't run since it won't compile.

Comment: It'll still Log the size of 0 with this code :) And `mine` cannot be final then reassigned

Comment: I don't think so... `mine =  new ArrayList();` shouldn't be possible as that field is `final` and `onCreate` is not a constructor. Also, 0 size will still be logged for the reason you already explained

Comment: @cricket_007 Yes, you are right. Removed inilialization line from `onCreate()`. Thanks

Comment: You're welcome, but third time now, that log statment is almost 100% likely to not be greater than zero

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the response after the request. See code comments

```
public class ActivityApplicationsList extends Activity 
    implements Callback<ArrayList<AppModel>> { // Implement callback here

    // These are final, so make them fields
    final ArrayList<StructApplication> mine = new ArrayList<>();
    final APIService service = ServiceGenerator.createService(APIService.class, "2015-03-01 14:26:00", "123456", "123456");

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_applications_list);

        populateDataFromServer();
    }

    // Callback implementation
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<ArrayList<AppModel>> call, Response<ArrayList<AppModel>> response) {

        final ArrayList<AppModel> responseBody = response.body();

        for(AppModel model : responseBody){

            StructApplication structApplication = new StructApplication();
            structApplication.setName(String.valueOf(model.getAppId()));
            structApplication.setId(model.getAppId());
            structApplication.setAppVersionReleaseDate(model.getAppVersionReDate());
            structApplication.setAppDeleted(model.getAppDeleted());

            mine.add(structApplication);
      }

      // adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); // Need this if using ListView
      Log.d("SIZE", ""+mine.size()); // Correct size
  }

  @Override
  public void onFailure(Call<ArrayList<AppModel>> call, Throwable t) {
    // error
  }

  private void populateDataFromServer() { // this is void; it can't return
      service.getApp().enqueue(ActivityApplicationsList.this);
  }
```

---

Suggestion, make this constructor

```
public class StructApplication {
    public StructApplication(AppModel model) {
        setName(String.valueOf(model.getAppId());
        setId(model.getAppId());
        setAppDeleted(model.getAppDeleted());
        setAppVersionReleaseDate(model.getAppVersionReDate());
    }
}
```

Then, that loop can simply be

```
mine.add(new StructApplication(model));
```